# In Scrapy, How to set time limit for each url?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl multiple websites using Scrapy link extractor and follow as TRUE (recursive) .. Looking for a solution to set the time limit to crawl for each url in start_urls list.

Thanks

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `download_timeout` meta parameter for `scrapy.Request`.

To use it in starting urls, you need to override `self.start_requests(self)` function, something like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    # 10 seconds for first url
    yield Request(self.start_urls[0], meta={'download_timeout': 10})
    # 60 seconds for first url
    yield Request(self.start_urls[1], meta={'download_timeout': 60})
```

You can read more about Request special meta keys here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` [setting](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std:setting-CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT)

For example, call your spider like this:

scrapy crawl DmozSpider -s CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT=10

Answer (score -2):

Use a Timeout object!

```
import signal

class Timeout(object):
    """Timeout class using ALARM signal."""
    class TimeoutError(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.sec)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        signal.alarm(0)# disable alarm

    def raise_timeout(self, *args):
        raise Timeout.TimeoutError('TimeoutError')
```

Then you can call your extractor inside a with statement like this:

```
with Timeout(10): #10 seconds
    try:
        do_what_you_need_to_do
    except Timeout.TimeoutError:
        #break, continue or whatever else you may need
```

Comment: Can you share an example using scrapy ? Thanks

Comment: It is not related to scrapy, you can use it with anything you want, just add the function call (or the piece of code) that need to be under-time-control into the try/except block and it is done.

Comment: I don't think it would work in this case or with scrapy downloader in general.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Why not? It should rise TimeoutError is the execution of your code is taking more than you expect. That's what gsuresh92 wants right?

Comment: I don't know, I've just never encountered anyone needing this since processing of the page is usually the fastest part, and can't really imagine it taking 10 seconds or even 5. Setting http timeouts for requests however, is very common and has bunch of usages.

Comment: @Granitosaurus The guy here is "Looking for a solution to set the time limit to crawl..." My answer offers a general way to do that not limiting the timeout to the connection response but to whatever else may get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work in scrapy and is very likely to break scrapy's twisted/reactor based asynchronicity